# Reuse logic between frontend (SvelteKit) and backend (Django)

Tags: python, node.js, sveltekit

I am building a webshop where we have complicated logic to determine which offers are valid for which products, based on which products you already own, what's in your basket, and a bunch more rules. Up until now this code has always lived in the backend (Django with Django REST Framework), and every time you'd add something into your basket we'd have to fetch all products again to get the changed prices, based on which offers were applied. This is quite slow, leading to a bad UX.

We want to run all this code in the frontend: we have the list of products, we have the list of offers and their rules, we know what's in the basket, we what what you already own, so we can apply the offers to the basket and to all the products in the shop, completely separate from the backend. Apart from the initial fetching of the necessary data, no more requests to the backend should be necessary any more. When you add something to the basket all the logic would re-run in the client. That's the idea.

But of course we want to also run this logic in the backend when checking out the basket. Can't rely on the frontend to tell the backend which offers were applied! And this is where my question begins: what is the best/easiest way to share this code? The frontend is a SvelteKit app built with TypeScript while the backend is all Django and Python.

I don't want to compile TS to Python or the other way around, where we'd end up with 2 pieces of logic that we need to keep in sync and make sure that behaves 100% the same. I want to run the exact same piece of code from the frontend and the backend, if that makes sense.

My only idea is to put the code in a SvelteKit endpoint, which could be called by both the frontend client, and by the Django backend. Just post all the info (a product, all offers, the basket, owned products, etc) and return the valid offers for this product, something like that. The downside though is that the code wouldn't actually run in the frontend - the frontend would still be calling a backend endpoint. It feels like it should be possible to do better than that.

Are there better ways? Would SvelteKit actions work? I haven't used them so I don't know if they run in the frontend client, or if that only happens when used from forms with the `use:enhance` action. Or maybe I can put the code in a separate NPM module that I can import on the frontend and somehow call from within Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment my plan is to write a TypeScript function that I can import in the frontend, and also in a SvelteKit endpoint. The Django backend can then talk to the SvelteKit endpoint - just post all the data needed for the calculations and get back the JSON with the valid offers.

Only one function to test and maintain. Only downside is that the Django backend needs to do an HTTP request but honestly since it's only needed when checking out the basket that's a huge improvement to the current situation.